# NextJS dynamic routes with dynamic component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to create 3 dynamic pages with different render component for each.

```
// components/AboutPage.js
export default function AboutPage({ template }){
  return <h1>{template}</h1>
}
```

```
// components/ContactPage.js
export default function ContactPage({ template }){
  return <h1>{template}</h1>
}
```

```
// components/BlogPage.js
export default function BlogPage({ template }){
  return <h1>{template}</h1>
}
```

And the route file.

```
// pages/[slug].js
import AboutPage from '../components/AboutPage'
import BlogPage from '../components/BlogPage'
import ContactPage from '../components/ContactPage'

export default function DynamicPage({ page }) {
  switch (page?.template) {
    case 'aboutPage':
      return <AboutPage {...page} />
    case 'blogPage':
      return <BlogPage {...page} />
    case 'contactPage':
      return <ContactPage {...page} />
    default:
      return null
  }
}

export const getStaticPaths = () => {
  const page = {
    template: 'aboutPage',
    slug: 'about'
  }
  return {
    props: {
      page
    }
  }
}

export const getStaticPaths = () => {
  const fetchedData = [
    {
      template: 'aboutPage',
      slug: 'about'
    },
    {
      template: 'contactPage',
      slug: 'contact'
    },
    {
      template: 'blogPage',
      slug: 'blog'
    }
  ]

  return {
    paths: fetchedData.map(({ slug }) => ({ params: {slug} })),
    fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}
```

My site is generated on build time, and my concern with this is the final JavaScript bundle size may include all 3 components and even when page is `AboutPage` for example.

I have not seen any related solution, NextJS has `dynamic()` but not sure if it helps my case? Or any way how can I make this work?

Comment: You could try using the bundle analyzer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer

Comment: I was looking for something like this, thank you Andrew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [next/dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

Add:

```
const AboutPage = dynamic(
  () => import("../components/AboutPage"),
);
```

instead of

```
import AboutPage from '../components/AboutPage'
```

Comment: Exactly! I didn't knew much about `dynamic()`. Initially I thought this was just for Client side and import would happen Synchronous and cause delay on render, but it worked even on SSG also.